# Set class on prev() if this is empty (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to addClass on prev() if $(this) is empty or removeClass if itsn't, but can't make it work:

```
function sfVide(){
    var noentry = false;
    $('.sf').each(function(){
        if($(this).val().trim()==""){
            noentry = true;
            $(this).prev().addClass("test");
        }
      else {
    $(this).prev().removeClass("test");
        }
    });
    return noentry;
}
```

HTML

```
<a class="sf--trigger">Subs</a>
<div class="sf"></div>
```

Live codepen for testing: https://codepen.io/mSyx/pen/MWayKQx

Comment: When you say it's not working... have you looked in the DOM inspector to see if the class is being added/removed? Also, your `return` statement won't do much.

Comment: [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) gets the value of form elements.

Comment: any way to get the inside value ? (what's in between <div>s)

Comment: `text()` or `html()`

Comment: I really thought the issue was in my writing and not the .val() thing itself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val()` is for use with `input` elements. In your example, you should probably use [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) (you could also use [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/)):

```js
$('.sf').each(function(){
    if( $(this).text().trim() == "" )
    {
        noentry = true;
        $(this).prev().addClass("test");
    }
    else 
    {
      $(this).prev().removeClass("test");
    }
});
```

```css
.btn {
  background: blue;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.btn.test {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn"></a>
<div class="sf"></div>
```

Comment: o, okay. thanks a lot. :)